# What is the fastest logic gate?

Tags: digital-logic, cpu, math

I have been told that the fastest logic gate family is ECL.

My first question: Is this true?

In this or another family (Depending on the answer to the above question),
Is there any particular gate who's internal structure is:

simpler, faster, requires less energy, creates less electrical noise e.t.c. ?

Comment: Note that this is only true for discrete logic; almost all integrated logic is CMOS.

Comment: You want the Holy Grail of logic design, the single logic type that is best at everything? It doesn't exist, and that's exactly why there are many different logic families.

Comment: What I'm more trying to get at is that by switching my bus wires around.  I could get away with using either an 'and' gate or a 'nand' gate.  I'm trying to discern if within any given logic family, which is more efficient?

Comment: Or rather is there any innate differences in simplicity, speed, energy consumption, interference between different types of gates (and, or, nand, nor) where each gate is constructed the same way e.g. Diodes, transistors, relays?

Comment: This question may justify the use of BJTs in modern circuit design.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ECL is both the fastest logic family and has the simplest internal structure of modern logic families, but like other bipolar-only families it has a not insignificant power draw. It is also incompatible with other logic families due to its signal voltages.

If you're looking for a logic family for general use, my recommendation would be the 74LVC CMOS family. It takes a supply of 1.65V to 5.5V, and uses normal CMOS signaling levels. It comes as surface mount only, but provides flexibility in that it is possible to get devices with as few as a single gate in a SOT23-5 package.

Comment: ECL requires very good power rail decoupling due to its speed, its edges.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found an ultra fast logic gate which is faster than ECL.
Please look at the following link to find its data sheet.
http://www.analog.com/en/products/hmc722lp3e.html

Comment: Can you add some more information beside the link?

Answer (score 0):

1. ECL processor caches are usually implemented with both ECL SRAM and BiCMOS technology [CMOS SRAM/DRAM with ECL driver/interface].
2. 4T SRAM is ideal for ECL.
3. BJT would consume less power than FET.
4. ECL becomes still faster by increasing fan-in/fan-out number and furthermore could employ terminated lines and complementary outputs as well as emitter dotting for even higher speed performance.
5. Multi-level series-gating improves upon the standard ECL.
6. ECL is almost 6.5 times faster than the fastest CMOS.
7. ECL dynamic power consumption is nearly constant at any operating frequency.
8. The transistor budget for an ECL CPU is almost 4.3 times lower than for a CMOS CPU. However, CMOS transistor shrink reduces overall number of field-effect transistors simultaneously switching.
9. Main memory efficiency can be enhanced by low-level programming.
10. ECL features stable power draw during switching hence does not have short-circuit power.